# Using racadm to change from Dedicated to LOM1?

Tags: dell-poweredge, drac, rhel8

Is it possible to use racadm to change iDRAC config from the default *dedicated* port to one of the server's main NIC/LOM ports?

There is relatively little in the documentation beyond [configuring the network settings](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/idrac9-lifecycle-controller-v4.x-series/idrac_4.00.00.00_racadm/setniccfg?guid=guid-e4833698-0656-47ff-8615-a5962f9835da&lang=en-us) (ip/subnet/gateway), which is done with:

```
racadm setniccfg -s $ipaddress $subnetmask $gateway
```

I am able to view the full network config (as well as which port the iDRAC is configured to use with:

```
racadm getniccfg
```

What options/arguments would I use to change from iDRAC dedicated to NIC1 port?

Answer (score 1):

Continued digging around online and ran across the solution. Reposting here as it was pretty hard to find (Dell server support guys were stumped as well)

**Check iDRAC config**

```
racadm getniccfg
```

**Verify which port is in use**
*(change eno1 to eth1 or whatever your server is configured as)*

```
ethtool eno1
ethtool eno2 
ethtool eno3
ethtool eno4
(check last line of output for "Link detected: yes")
```

**Check iDRAC NIC Selection**

```
racadm get iDRAC.NIC.Selection
```

**Set iDRAC to use shared network port LOM1**
*(look for link detected in output from ethtool above)*

```
racadm set iDRAC.NIC.Selection LOM1
```

**Check iDRAC NIC Selection**
racadm get iDRAC.NIC.Selection

**Set iDRAC network configuration**

```
racadm setniccfg -s <ipv4_address> <subnetmask> <ipv4_gateway>
```

**Check iDRAC config**

```
racadm getniccfg
```

You should see something like:

```
LOM Status:
NIC Selection   = LOM1
Link Detected   = No
Speed           = Unknown
Duplex Mode     = Unknown
Active NIC      = None
Active LOM in Shared Mode = None
FailOver LOM in Shared Mode = None

Static IPv4 settings:
Static IP Address    = <ipv4_address>
Static Subnet Mask   = <subnetmask>
Static Gateway       = <ipv4_gateway>
```

**To change back from LOM1 to Dedicated**

```
racadm set iDRAC.NIC.Selection 1
```

**Additional iDRAC.NIC options**

For a full list of config options use

```
racadm help iDRAC.NIC
```

**To view full system config**

```
racadm getsysinfo
```

Comment: (Obligatory legal note: I work for Dell) Risking being overly opinionated here: That sort of stuff isn't typically advertised because unless you have a very good reason to do this we do not recommend it. Your management should always be out of band and physically separate from prod. Doing this in a lab it's fine but as a former red teamer who owned more than one SuperMicro server because people would leave the IPMI interface hung out, I would carefully examine the motivation for doing this in production. Example bad (but common) reason: Only wanting to run one cable.

Comment: In our case, we have cabling to both dedicated and LOM1, however having spent quite a bit of time with helpful Dell techs, and our own local NOC, we've nearly reached the conclusion that the iDRAC port is borked somehow. Our connectivity is OK over LOM1, but setting it back to Dedicated results in no ping and no access to iDRAC (in spite of NOC seeing device MAC, and confirming cabling is good, and that we have link at the Dedicated port. We all agree that it's 100% better to have the iDRAC on its own dedicated port.